# Removing contour lines from ggplot geom_crossbar

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

Below is an example of dataset and the plot code with geom_crossbar that is geeting me close to what I'm looking for, except that I can't find a way to remove the black contour line around the bars.

```
data = data.frame(age = c(10,12,14,16,18), 
                  height_min = c(120,140,148,150,150),
                  height_max = c(150,165,172,175,175))
ggplot(data) +
  geom_crossbar(aes(ymin= height_min, ymax=height_max, x=age, y=height_min),
                fill = "gray70", fatten=0) + 
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
  theme(panel.border = element_blank()) + 
  theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")) +
  labs(x=expression(paste("Age (years)")), 
       y=expression(paste("Height (cm)"))) +
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1,1,1,1), "cm")) +
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=20),
        axis.title=element_text(size=30,face="bold"))
```

How can I remove the black contour lines around the bars?

Answer (score 1):

You can add "linetype = 0" or "color = NA" in geom_crossbar. "size=0" works too if you don't need to export the plot (otherwise the bars disappear).

Here is the code in case that could be useful for others:

```
data = data.frame(age = c(10,12,14,16,18), 
                  height_min = c(120,140,148,150,150),
                  height_max = c(150,165,172,175,175))
ggplot(data) +
  geom_crossbar(aes(ymin= height_min, ymax=height_max, x=age, y=height_min),
                fill = "gray70", fatten=0, linetype = 0) + 
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
  theme(panel.border = element_blank()) + 
  theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")) +
  labs(x=expression(paste("Age (years)")), 
       y=expression(paste("Height (cm)"))) +
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1,1,1,1), "cm")) +
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=20),
        axis.title=element_text(size=30,face="bold"))
```

Thanks dc37 for your comment!

Comment: You can also use `color = NA` in `geom_crossbar`